# simplify nested for loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, refactoring

I need help in simplifying a nested for loop or is it the optimal way already without adding more complexity

```
var multiParamValues = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
multiParamValues.Add("ParamA", new string[] {"1", "2"});
multiParamValues.Add("ParamB", new string[] {"55", "56"});

var nameOfParameter = multiParamValues.ToList();
var numberOfParameters = nameOfParameter[0].Value.Length;

for (var k = 0; k < numberOfParameters; k++)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < multiParamValues.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", nameOfParameter[i].Key, nameOfParameter[i].Value[k]);
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
ParamA, 1
ParamB, 55
ParamA, 2
ParamB, 56
```

Comment: Can't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a big deal but you don't have to convert Dictionary to List.

```cs
var multiParamValues = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
multiParamValues.Add("ParamA", new string[] { "1", "2" });
multiParamValues.Add("ParamB", new string[] { "55", "56" });

var numberOfParameters = multiParamValues.First().Value.Length;

for (var k = 0; k < numberOfParameters; k++)
{
    foreach (var item in multiParamValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value[k]);
    }
}
```

Please note that the order of elements in Dictionary is NOT guaranteed by C# spec.

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements you can make.
First you can [initialize dictionary](https://dailydotnettips.com/initialization-of-dictionary-dictionary-initializer-in-c-6-0/) in more compact way:

```
var multiParamValues = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {"ParamA", new[] {"1", "2"}},
    {"ParamB", new[] {"55", "56"}}
};
```

Or

```
var multiParamValues1 = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    ["ParamA"] = new[] {"1", "2"},
    ["ParamB"] = new[] {"55", "56"}
};
```

Second you can eliminate use of indexes by using foreach instead of for loop:

```
foreach (var multiParamValue in multiParamValues)
{
    foreach (var value in multiParamValue.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", multiParamValue.Key, value);
    }
}
```

And last you can simplify you output string using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{key}, {value}");
```

So, the final code could look like this:

```
var multiParamValues = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {"ParamA", new[] {"1", "2"}},
    {"ParamB", new[] {"55", "56"}}
};

foreach (var paramValue in multiParamValues)
{
    foreach (var value in paramValue.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{paramValue.Key}, {value}");
    }
}
```